# How to add a custom button on the Home Tab using VSTO

Tags: outlook, office365, vsto, outlook-addin

I am creating an outlook VSTO to add a custom button to the home ribbon. I have added the code to the ribbon.xml:

```
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui">
  <ribbon>
    <tabs>
      <tab idMso="TabHome">
    <group id="Phishing" label="Phishing">
      <button id="Phishing_Email" label="Phishing_Email" size="large" />
    </group>
  </tab>
</tabs>
</ribbon>
</customUI>
```

and added the code to ThisAddin.cs but when testing the code the button does not appear and i dont get any errors.

Can anybody help?

Comment: Did you turn on addin error reporting in File | Options | Advanced | Developers | Show addin user interface errors?

Comment: yes pal it is turned on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I have noticed that you use an old namespace for the ribbon XML:

```html
<customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2006/01/customui">
```

Instead, you need to specify the following one:

```html
   <customUI xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2009/07/customui">
```

Then make sure the add-in is loaded by the host application and the `GetCustomUI` method is invoked. Note, you must return this ribbon XML markup only for inspector windows.

The [Walkthrough: Create a custom tab by using Ribbon XML](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-creating-a-custom-tab-by-using-ribbon-xml) describes all the required steps for creating a custom Fluent UI.

Comment: Cheers pal that worked it now shows it on the home screen. If I create a new email it opens a new box and gives an error as the 'home' tab is not there which is on the xml above. How can I prevent this

Comment: Looks like there is no such built-in tabs on the new inspector. You need to filter item types by checking parameters passed to the `GetCustomUI` method.

Comment: I'd recommend marking the post as an answer if it helped to find the cause.

Comment: i've tired adding a try catch in but it flags up the error